# Proper way to get input field value with AJAX

Tags: forms, ajax, 9

I want to do some calculations in node edit form vith ajax. Form fields is created via UI, so i need to drill into field array to get value(s). Maximum result what i have is replacing target field with result of #defaul_value of source fields. Nothing happens when i change source.

```
<?
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;

function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    
    $form['field_source']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax']  = array(
        'callback' => 'myAjaxCallback',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'calc',
    );

    $form['field_source2']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax']  = array(
        'callback' => 'myAjaxCallback',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'calc',
    );

    $form['field_target']['#prefix'] = '<div id="calc">';
    $form['field_target']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['field_target']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    
 /* some calculations */
    $s1 = $form['field_souce']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value']; /*  HOW TO GET PROPER SOURCE VALUES "ON FLY" WHEN EDITOR CHANGES IT? */
    $s2 = $form['field_souce2']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'];
    $result = $s1 * $s2;

    $form['field_target']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $result;
}

function myAjaxCallback($form, FormStateInterface $form_state)  {
   return $form['field_target'];
}
```

Calculations gives result, but only with values which already submitted, so when i change source values AJAX firing & fading, but nothing happens whith target.
What i try is get values with:

```
$s1 = $form_state->getValue('source'); <-- gives "0" $result
$s1 = $form['field_souce']['widget'][0]['value'] <-- get error Unsupported operand types
```

Answer (score 0):

found a way to get input value

```
$values = $form_state->getUserInput();
$s1 = $values['field_source']['0']['value'];
$s2 = $values['field_source2']['0']['value'];
```

Comment: Should be noted that **[getUserInput](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AgetUserInput/8.2.x)** says, `These are raw and unvalidated, so should not be used without a thorough understanding of security implications.`